# precise daily cd vs point release

Tags: 12.04, installation

I wanted to download precise live and alternate cd iso , but I'm confused on what to choose among daily build vs point release 12.04.2 .

All I know is daily cd will have updated versions of packages. 
But will daily build introduce new features? And thereby possible new bugs? 
Is daily build as stable as the point release?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daily builds provide new features, but are bleeding edge, and might not be suitable for production environment. For day-to-day mission-critical tasks or other tasks which demand certain amount of stability, the stable release 12.04.2 should be used.

You can use daily build on virtualbox / as a separate install to test the new features, or develop new features. In general, its advised not to use the daily build for regular systems.